# Gatsby soruce contentful body

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using gatsby srouce contentful get my blog post from contenful. I'm trying to get the body as rich text or json but the only option graphql will let me use is raw which gives me back a bunch of objects and the text which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Make sure you have imported gatsby-source-contentful using:

```
npm install gatsby-source-contentful
```

Step 2. Add this to you imports:

```
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
```

Step 3. Your query should look something like this

```
export const query = graphql`
query($slug: String!){
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
        title
        publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        body{
            raw
        }
    }
}`
```

Step 4. return {renderRichText(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body)}

```
const Blog = (props) => {
return(
    <Layout>
        <h1>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.title}</h1>
        <p>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.publishedDate}</p>
        <div>{renderRichText(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body)}</div>
    </Layout>

)
```

}

I hope this helps, this is my first answer on stack overflow and I believe we are following the same bootcamp based on the way you have posed the question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t0vNu2fCCM&t=590s&ab_channel=AndrewMead

Message me if you would like to cooperate and learn from each other.

This might help too: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#query-rich-text-content-and-references

---

Adding another solution:

```
export const query = graphql`
query($slug: String!){
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
        title
        publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        body{
            raw
            references {
                fixed(width: 750) {
                  width
                  height
                  src
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

add references to the raw data.

```
const Blog = (props) => {
const options = {
    renderNode: {
        "embedded-asset-block": (node) => {
            const alt = "test"
            const url = props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.references[0].fixed.src
            return <img src={url} alt={alt}/>
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in the render section:

```
<div>{renderRichText(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body, options)}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`raw` object is a new "feature" added in the latest versions of `gatsby-source-contentful`. According to the [docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/):

> **Note**: Be aware that previous versions of the Gatsby Contentful source plugin used a `json` field. This got replaced with `raw` to give
> you more flexibility in rendering and to fix performance issues.

That "flexibility" that Contentful points, is the capability of customizing the output from the `return` statement of the component that will parse that `raw` response. Ideally, you should have something like:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

The snippet above, allows you to customize the response for each `MARKS` and `BLOCKS` entry, adding the proper styles if desired and wrapping it in any structure that you may need. The component above will allow you to parse that raw response and return the correct component.

You can check for further details the Contentful docs provided in this answer and the [`gatsby-source-contentful` plugin docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/).